# NumPy writing windings instead of numbers to CSV in ArcMap

Tags: python, arrays, random, arcgis, arcpy

I'm using this code:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

f = open("F:\INTRO_PY\LAB_7\lab_7.csv","w")
array = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

f.write(array)
f.close
```

in order to create a 1000x1000 random array in arcpy.

This is what I get when I open the csv:
[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpxx8.png)

I have absolutely no idea why it's doing this, and I'm at my wit's end. Any advice would be really, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In order to save it to CSV, you need to can use `numpy`'s [**`numpy.savetxt`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
np.savetxt(
    r"F:\INTRO_PY\LAB_7\lab_7.csv",
    np.random.rand(1000,1000),
    delimiter=','
)
```

The `delimeter thus specifies what one uses to split the different values.

Note that you can only save 1D arrays or 2D arrays to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to store a numpy in a file, you should convert it to a string first.

Something like the following:

```
f = open("test.csv","w")
    array = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
    f.write(str(array))
    f.close
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple solution.